# DrayTek VigorPro 5510 + IPCop

Tags: firewall, ipcop, draytek

Our network uses a DrayTek VigorPro 5510.
The content filtering on this isn't particularly strong - It work's on IP ranges - for example, our 10.0.10.xx range can view anything, but 10.0.65.xx has downloads, certain sites, facebook etc... blocked.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use IPCop alongside the DrayTek? And how would I go about configuring this?

Also- I am hoping that it's possible to filter content profiles based on Active Directory membership ACL?

For example...

the "IT" group can view everything
the "Customer Service" group has very limited internet access
"Mangers" group (for managers of depts) can access some sites that the above group cannot.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with IPCop? If filtering, it might better be achieved with a dedicated server running Squid, that will certianly support applying filtering based on LDAP (AD) group membership and can authenticate Windows clients automatically via NTLM.

Comment: yes, basically JUST filtering... so Squid is capable of doing this? Just the filtering part..? how would i set up the draytek to pass all traffic through the squid server?

Comment: Squid, or maybe combine it with a product like DansGuardian for more fine grained filtering. 

You would setup the proxy infront of your router (client->proxy->router->internet) and configure the clients to use it, or set it as the clients' default gateway and run it in transparent mode.